# error: msys: signature from "XXX" is invalid

Tags: arch-linux, terminal, signature

How can I fix the error in the terminal on Arch Linux below?

```
error: msys: signature from "David Macek <david.macek.0@gmail.com>" is invalid
```

This happen when I execute command.

```
sudo pacman-key --populate msys
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a known issue, with various causes over the recent years: https://github.com/msys2/MSYS2-packages/issues/2343

In short:

Make sure your system is configured to use [the actual repository](https://repo.msys2.org/msys/x86_64/) and not an old mirror site that might be out of date or stopped updating altogether.

Use a web browser to visit the repository URL (linked above). Find the newest version of the `msys2-keyring-*-any.pkg.tar.zst` package. At the time of this writing, it is `msys2-keyring-1~20230703-1-any.pkg.tar.zst`.

Download the package and its associated `.sig` file manually, then verify its signature and install it:

```
curl -O https://repo.msys2.org/msys/x86_64/msys2-keyring-1~20230703-1-any.pkg.tar.zst
curl -O https://repo.msys2.org/msys/x86_64/msys2-keyring-1~20230703-1-any.pkg.tar.zst.sig
pacman-key --verify msys2-keyring-1~20230703-1-any.pkg.tar.zst.sig
pacman -U msys2-keyring-1~20230703-1-any.pkg.tar.zst
```

The `pacman-key --verify ...` step may still display a warning about invalid signature, because it's still using the old keyring; that's expected if your current keyring is multiple versions out of date. Any other errors would suggest the keyring file is incomplete or damaged in transit and should be downloaded again.

After the keyring is successfully updated, you could re-run the `pacman-key --verify ...` step, and it should now run without errors.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But an error appeared.
`
``
pacman-key --verify msys2-keyring-1~20230703-1-any.pkg.tar.zst.sig~
==> Checking msys2-keyring-1~20230703-1-any.pkg.tar.zst.sig~... (detached)
grep: msys2-keyring-1~20230703-1-any.pkg.tar.zst.sig~: No such file or directory
gpg: can't open 'msys2-keyring-1~20230703-1-any.pkg.tar.zst.sig~': No such file or directory
gpg: verify signatures failed: No such file or directory
==> ERROR: The signature identified by msys2-keyring-1~20230703-1-any.pkg.tar.zst.sig~ could not be verified.```

Comment: There seems to be an extra `~` at the end of your command, after `...sig`.